# Discord.py|VoiceChannelEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

the code doesn't work:

```
async def online(ctx, channel: discord.VoiceChannel.id('710791819524009066')):
        await ctx.edit(name='Online:' + getonline())
```

Error:

```
 async def online(ctx, channel: discord.VoiceChannel.id('710791819524309066')):
TypeError: 'member_descriptor' object is not callable
```

How fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what's going on here. You didn't explain what you're actually trying to do and it is hard to find out by your code. First of all You can't do `channel: discord.VoiceChannel.id('710791819524009066'))` perhaps you meant `discord.VoiceChannel`, < that also means one could just give the channel ID on command. Or make you own class that excepts `.id`. And also you can't do `ctx.edit` as if I rember correctly context doesn't have an attribute 'edit'. And edit doesn't even have Keyward argument 'name' if I rember correctly. Did you meant `ctx.send(content='Online:' + getonline())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do `discord.VoiceChannel.id('710791819524009066')`, but you can do `discord.VoiceChannel.id` meaning
You could do:

```py
async def online(ctx, channel: discord.VoiceChannel):
    if channel.id == 664967449908609024: # Check if channel ID given is 664967449908609024
        await ctx.send(content="Online " + getonline())
```

Command: `online <channel ID>` - Because we're using `discord.VoiceChannel` we can just give a channel ID if can't mention a voice channel.